# tkinter print value from getting input fields

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

Hello I am trying to get information from input fields and trying to print giris.get() ,but ı cant access this one where is the problem ? I searched a lot in stackoverflow ,but none of them solved my problem

```
 from selenium import webdriver
from tkinter import *



root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x400")
root.title("Spotify Ortak Sarkilar")


giris = Entry(root,width = 50,
bg = "black",
fg = "white",
 )

giris2 = Entry(root,width = 50,
bg = "black",
fg = "white",
)
giris3 = Entry(root,width = 50,
bg = "black",
fg = "white",
)
get1 = ""
get2 = ""
x = ""
def myclick():
  global x
  x = (giris.get())
  y = (giris2.get())
  root.destroy()

giris.pack(padx= 50,pady = 20)
giris2.pack(padx= 50,pady = 10)
giris.insert(0,"1.Spotify Linkini giriniz.")
giris2.insert(0,"2.Spotify Linkini giriniz.")

buton = Button(root,text ="Yolla", command =lambda: myclick , fg = "white"  ,bg = "black" ,padx= 50)
buton.pack(pady = 100)
print(x)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

myClick isn't being executed, to fix that don't use lambda.

```
buton = Button(root,text ="Yolla", command =myclick , fg = "white"  ,bg = "black" ,padx= 50)
```

Comment: How is it not working? If I add code to print x and y to the myclick function the appropriate values are printed to the console when the button is clicked.

Comment: But ı want to access this x out of the def function,I can print in def function but that is not ı want

Comment: Why are you destroying root when the button us clucked? That will stop all code execution.

Comment: Nothing will change if ı deleted this part

Comment: Delete which part. Can you explain what you actually want to do?

Comment: from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x400")
root.title("Spotify Ortak Sarkilar")


giris = Entry(root,width = 50,
bg = "black",
fg = "white",
 )
giris.pack(pady = 30)
bos = []
def tiklama():
  bos.append(giris.get())
  
buton = Button(root,text = "Tikla",command = tiklama )
buton.pack(pady= 30)
print(bos)



root.mainloop()

Comment: I wanna access the bos array update this every time but ı cant access the bos array

Comment: There's no array in the original code, and don't post code in comments - it's unreadable and unformatted. If something has changed edit the original question.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to get information from input fields and trying to print
> giris.get() ,but ı cant access this one where is the problem.

The problem can be fixed.

Add `print()` on `myclick()` function.

code:

```
def myclick():  
  x = (giris.get())
  y = (giris2.get())
  print(x)
  print(y)
  root.destroy()
```

Output:

```
1.Spotify Linkini giriniz.deepika padukone
2.Spotify Linkini giriniz.Wallis Day
```